# GSheet Appscript unsuccessful loops output

Tags: loops, pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets, foreach

I successfully created two functions which are to build data report in my template based on a certain data (invoice) and to auto-download the report as a PDF file.

But when I tried to loop those functions because I have many invoices to be downloaded as pdf files. This is my function:

```
function downloadNota() {
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var xs = ws.getSheetByName('Print Nota');
  var lr = xs.getLastRow();
  var nota = xs.getRange('B2:B' + lr).getValues();
  var number = nota.map(function (r) { return r.toString().replace('\[ | \]', '') });
  number.forEach(function (invoice) {
    printInvoice(+invoice)
  });
  downloadPdf(noInvoice)
}
```

But when I run the function, data in the template become blank (image attached).

[image]

Here is my function to fill the data in my template:

```
function printInvoice(noInvoice) {
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = ws.getSheetByName('NOTA INVOICE2');
  var dd = ws.getSheetByName('GABUNGAN');
  ss.getRange('B10').setValue(noInvoice);
  ss.getRange('A14:G120').activate();
  ss.getActiveRangeList().clear({ contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true })
    .setBackground(null)
    .setBorder(false, false, false, false, false, false)
    .setFontWeight(null)
    .setFontColor(null)
    .breakApart();
  var allData = dd.getRange('A5:S').getValues();
  var dataString = allData.filter(String);
  var listData = dataString.map(function (r) { return r; });
  var neededData = listData.filter(listData => listData[2] === noInvoice);
  var nData = neededData.length;
  var data = [];
  if (!neededData) return;
  for (var i = 0; i < nData; i++) {
    newData = [neededData[i][5], neededData[i][6], neededData[i][8], neededData[i][9], neededData[i][7], (neededData[i][8] - neededData[i][9]) * neededData[i][7]];
    data.push(newData);
  }
  ss.getRange(14, 6, nData, 2).mergeAcross();
  ss.getRange(14, 1, nData, 7).activate();
  ss.getActiveRangeList()
    .setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, '#000000', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID)
  ss.getRange(14, 1, nData + 8, 7).activate();
  ss.getActiveRangeList()
    .setHorizontalAlignment("right");
  ss.getRange(14, 1, nData, 2).activate();
  ss.getActiveRangeList()
    .setHorizontalAlignment("center");
  ss.getRange(14, 5, nData, 1).activate();
  ss.getActiveRangeList()
    .setHorizontalAlignment("center");
  ss.getRange(14 + nData + 1, 2, 4, 1).activate();
  ss.getActiveRangeList()
    .setHorizontalAlignment("left");
  ss.getRange(14 + nData + 5, 1, 1, 7).activate();
  ss.getActiveRangeList().setBorder(true, false, false, false, false, false, '#000000', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
  ss.getRange(14, 1, nData, 6).setValues(data);
  ss.getRange(14 + nData + 2, 1).setValue('Status Pengiriman:');
  ss.getRange(14 + nData + 2, 2).setValue('SUDAH DIKIRIM');
  ss.getRange(14 + nData + 3, 1).setValue('Status Pembayaran:');
  ss.getRange(14 + nData + 3, 2).setValue('PAID');
  ss.getRange(14 + nData + 1, 6).setValue('SUBTOTAL :');
  ss.getRange(14 + nData + 1, 7).setFormulaR1C1("=SUM(R[-2]C[-1]:R[-" + (nData + 1) + "]C[-1])");
  ss.getRange(14 + nData + 2, 6).setValue('DPP :');
  ss.getRange(14 + nData + 2, 7).setFormula('=VLOOKUP(B10,{GABUNGAN!C5:C,GABUNGAN!Q5:Q},2,false)');
  ss.getRange(14 + nData + 3, 6).setValue('PPN (11%) :');
  ss.getRange(14 + nData + 3, 7).setFormula('=VLOOKUP(B10,{GABUNGAN!C5:C,GABUNGAN!R5:R},2,false)');
  ss.getRange(14 + nData + 4, 6).setValue('BIAYA PENGIRIMAN :');
  ss.getRange(14 + nData + 4, 7).setFormula('=VLOOKUP(B10,{GABUNGAN!C5:C,GABUNGAN!N5:N},2,false)');
  ss.getRange(14 + nData + 5, 6).setValue('GRAND TOTAL :');
  ss.getRange(14 + nData + 5, 7).setFormulaR1C1("=SUM(R[-2]C[0]:R[-4]C[0])");
  ss.getRange('B10').activate();
}
```

Here is what I hope to get as a PDF file downloaded:

[image]

Comment: And there are no errors in the execution log?  A few observations, I'm assuming `+invoice` is used to coerce the string to a number, and in `downloadPdf(noInvoice)` noInvoice is not defined.

Comment: Another observation try puttong `Logger.log("neededData = "+neededData);` before `if (!neededData) return;`  maybe its 0.

Comment: I must apologize. In the process of editing your question I somehow lost the second image.  Sorry

Comment: My recommendation is to rewrite the entire function without using activeRange or activate().  This code reminds me of macros which I simply don't read and move on to the next question.

Comment: Please share a copy / sample of your sheet and an example of the desired output

Comment: TheWizEd: sorry for my clumsy and thanks for reminding me that downloadPdf(noInvoice) is supposed to be downloadPdf(+invoice). 
Cooper: You rock!!!, thanks for your advice to change activeRange as a var and now my foreach function successfully runs well.
LorenaGomez : thanks for your time. Hope you guys have nice days :)

Comment: @Cooper: I have repaired the image that dropped out in your edit - it was in the first version.

Comment: I think will leave you in the good hands of TheWizEd.  Perhaps he can assist more effect than I was able.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the entire function without using activeRange or activate().
exp :

```
ss.getRange(14, 1, nData + 8, 7).activate();
  ss.getActiveRangeList()
    .setHorizontalAlignment("right");
```

REWRITE

```
var a = ss.getRange(14, 1, nData + 8, 7);
      a.setHorizontalAlignment("right");
```